# Odd jQuery looping bug

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

So I have a PHP page that returns XML to jQuery. I parse the XML and turn it into an object (myArray). When I console.log the Object, I see:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
STACKPAGEID: "Test"
WEBPAGE_TAG_ID: "2096"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
STACKPAGEID: "Test"
WEBPAGE_TAG_ID: "2175"
__proto__: Object
```

As you can see, there are 2 results that each have 2 fields (stackpageid, webpage_tag_id).

The problem is that when I run this loop:

```
$.each(myArray, function(index,item) {
    console.log(item.webpage_tag_id);
});
```

I will get:

```
undefined
undefined
```

I can't figure this out. Everything looks good - why is it undefined? The first result should be "2096" and the second result should be "2175". Anyone?

Comment: Are your xml element names in uppercase or is that output just the behavior of your browser console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language:

```
$.each(myArray, function(index,item) {
    console.log(item.WEBPAGE_TAG_ID);
});
```

Comment: Scratch that - the problem is a capitalisation. But in PHP, the field is in lower case. Odd one...

Comment: All I'm doing is console logging the PHP output and PHP is sending this (so why are things capitalized):<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <row>
    <webpage_tag_id>2096</webpage_tag_id>
    <stackPageID>Test</stackPageID>
  </row>
  <row>
    <webpage_tag_id>2175</webpage_tag_id>
    <stackPageID>Test</stackPageID>
  </row>
</response>